# Int型とCountableClosedRange<Int>を比較したい

Tags: swift

Corelocationでiphoneの磁器センサを使い方角を数値化して
その数値がある範囲にある間、特定の処理をしたいのですが
磁器センサの値と、レンジが比較できなくて困っています
コードは大まかに以下のような感じです

```
var CDR:Int = Int(newHeading.magneticHeading) //磁器センサの値が入り続ける

while CDR == 0...45{ //ここでIntとCountableClosedRange<Int>を比べるなと怒られる
   print("例")
}
```

このような処理をしたい場合どう比較すれば良いですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

パターンマッチ演算子（`~=`）を使います。

```
while 0...45 ~= CDR {
    ...
}
```

または`case ...`を使って書くこともできます。（`case ...`は内部的にパターンマッチ演算子（`~=`）が使用されます。上記のように書くのと同じことです。

```
while case 0...45 = CDR {
    ...
}
```

Comment: パターンマッチを否定したいときはどうすれば良いですか？例えば上のコードで言えば0...45の間でない時、みたいな感じです。

Comment: 否定をしたいときは、否定演算子を使います。`while !(0...45 ~= CDR)`「みたいな感じ」です。